# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() is not working with httppPostedFile in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I am working on a Kentico project where I have to integrate MetaScan into Kentico. I am trying to send a `HttpPosted` file through the method `callMetaScan(CMSFileUpload.PostedFile)` and I have the following callMetaScan method

```
private void callMetaScan(System.Web.HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile){ 


string strDate = string.Format("{0} GMT", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"));


System.Net.HttpWebRequest myReq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(myURI);


myReq.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate);


myReq.Method = "POST";


byte[] myBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StreamToString(httpPostedFile1.InputStream));‌


//byte[] myBytes = new byte[httpPostedFile.InputStream.Length];
//Read the file into the byte array.


httpPostedFile.InputStream.Read(myBytes, 0, myBytes.Length);


myReq.ContentLength = myBytes.Length;
myReq.ContentType = httpPostedFile.ContentType;


System.IO.Stream PostData = (System.IO.Stream)myReq.GetRequestStream();
PostData.Write(myBytes, 0, myBytes.Length);
PostData.Close();


System.Net.HttpWebResponse Response2 = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();



System.IO.StreamReader SR = default(System.IO.StreamReader);
SR = new System.IO.StreamReader(Response2.GetResponseStream());
string rslt = SR.ReadToEnd();
SR.Close();
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlRslt = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlRslt.LoadXml(rslt);

//if no final_scan_result, then save a copy of the xml and email us.
if (xmlRslt.SelectSingleNode(pathstring) != null)
{
    int finalScanResultCode = Int32.Parse(xmlRslt.SelectSingleNode(pathstring).InnerText);

}
else
{
    //Send Email about the XML
     Response.Write(“Unable to scan file.”);            
}
}
```

But my code is not working after requesting response System.Net.HttpWebResponse Response2 = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse(); 
Even I am not getting any exception.

Please suggest how I may fix this. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: You have a method called "StreamToString" which may be problematic.  It seems like your converting the input file to text and THEN to binary.  Then you're even reading the bytes back into the input stream of the posted file?  Not sure if that is supposed to be there.

Also, I don't think this is the issue, but you should incorporate some using statements to make sure all the streams get closed at the appropriate times.

Comment: One more thing, do you need to be adding in some sort of key/header so that the MetaScan API knows who you are?

Comment: Thank you so much John for your reply and advice. Now my code is running. You have caught the right point. Since I am encoding the file so I am not getting the actual image file after uploading an image. Here is my `StreamToString` 

method (I took it from an another problem post of stackoverflow)

    `public static string StreamToString(System.IO.Stream data)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(data);
        string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();

        return body;
    }`

Comment: Now I am able to upload the image file, but the problem is that it's already encoded so I am unable to see the actual image. Please help me here

Comment: If I am not encoding the file, then it is giving me position has changed error. I have used this code before the current encoding one `byte[] myBytes = new byte[myfile.PostedFile.InputStream.Length];` and got that error.

Comment: I am getting now protocol error. Any hints?

Comment: ask that in a new question, you won't get a response here

Comment: Hi McDowells, Thanks for your advice. I have created a thread for my [problem] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118600/getting-protocol-webexception-at-httpwebresponsemyreq-getresponse). but I am not getting any reply